# Restoring deleted mysql database

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have deleted my database using phpmyadmin from MAMP, but i have time machine attached to my laptop, so everything is backed up there. I saw folder name db under MAMP, under it. I see a lot of files. Is there a way if i can restore/import my database?

Answer (score 0):

You must have:

- ibdata1
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1
- .FRM files from your mysql_database folder
- Fresh installation of MAMP / MAMP Pro that you are willing to destroy
  (if need be)

Check this:
http://www.quora.com/Jordan-Ryan/Web-Dev/How-to-Recover-innoDB-MySQL-files-using-MAMP-on-a-Mac