# Restore WordPress Database From MAMP Time Machine Backup

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Few weeks ago I added some authors to my WordPress blog and today I 'accidentally' reseted my WordPress blog with a plugin - so I lost the authors. I checked the phpMyAdmin to see if my authors are there but there is only default 'admin'. I had a lot of authors with bios so re-adding them again is a no go :/.

I have a regular Time Machine backups and I believe my accidentally-deleted authors are still there somewhere. I found the `wp_users.frm` file but I have no idea how to restore/read it. How do I restore my WP authors without removing/replacing my current database? I would at least like to read the names and bios. Is there any way I could import the old database to some new 'dummy' one to not lose the current database?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061776/restoring-deleted-mysql-database

Comment: Also: http://efwjames.com/2015/11/how-to-quickly-backup-and-restore-mamps-phpmyadmin-databases/

Comment: NOT a duplicate, the method shown in your the link you shared involves a `Fresh installation of MAMP / MAMP Pro that you are willing to destroy (if need be)`. I want to keep my current database. Any workaround?

Comment: Anyways thank you for the link, I'll try backing up my current database and restoring and backing up and removing and relaunching and restoring AAAGH! Why are databases so hard to tweak. Calm down me. Thanks again for the link!